# Why encoding a face with the "num_jitters" parameter affects the encoding of another face (with the "num_jitters" parameter)

Tags: python, face-recognition

Why encoding a face with the "num_jitters" parameter affects the encoding of another face (with the "num_jitters" parameter as well)?

I have an `face_encode` variable, which is "Har.png" image encode (with `num_jitters = 10`)

When processing the same image and comparing them, I get the same value (`face_encode and test are identical`).

However, after uncommenting this line: `new = encode("Ani.png", 10)[0]` "Face_encode" and "test" become non-identical (`np.allclose(face_encode, test)` return `False`). This means that processing one face affects the encoding of another face.

Note: If we will change the `num_itters` to `1` in `new = encode("Ani.png", 1)[0]`, the `print(np.allclose(face_encode, test))` will give a True. This mean that `jittering` affect on face encode of another image

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np


face_encode = np.array([-0.03383258,  0.1522091 ,  0.00778023, -0.02392919, -0.12134701,
        0.02448359, -0.12119899,  0.00130317,  0.17482917, -0.00608639,
        0.07468938,  0.01706824, -0.21361005,  0.04690374, -0.10125306,
        0.13845484, -0.23481546, -0.1003552 , -0.09002965, -0.08902221,
        0.009046  ,  0.06367773, -0.01593469,  0.04676583, -0.17100905,
       -0.31411591, -0.08375659, -0.10543557,  0.04868974, -0.12692517,
        0.02808667, -0.0059777 , -0.1129951 , -0.03772227,  0.02010387,
        0.03789502, -0.04583764, -0.06205031,  0.18120724,  0.11010844,
       -0.12902826,  0.04678808,  0.03990007,  0.37248898,  0.17482039,
        0.10718967,  0.02596617, -0.05392049,  0.14223413, -0.26670438,
        0.07981005,  0.22440179,  0.02152029,  0.08013226,  0.06920523,
       -0.12548962,  0.0365652 ,  0.18923151, -0.24735497,  0.07125427,
        0.07109451,  0.0370005 , -0.02891098, -0.07094251,  0.22352193,
        0.13761494, -0.1292235 , -0.11606612,  0.12919654, -0.16925484,
       -0.08498519, -0.04782813, -0.11302817, -0.13826026, -0.34820935,
        0.0340745 ,  0.40744266,  0.17069298, -0.10228713,  0.01735803,
       -0.04485941, -0.05013431,  0.01530067,  0.05060982, -0.19970088,
       -0.01855213, -0.04743322,  0.05434962,  0.15309754,  0.0527404 ,
       -0.02121131,  0.14636354,  0.03430861, -0.0306342 ,  0.01154729,
        0.04730092, -0.2055707 , -0.0561384 , -0.15399964, -0.05845002,
        0.04407276, -0.04798348,  0.02185482,  0.16238688, -0.17582887,
        0.19120233,  0.0242596 , -0.08013647, -0.03035241,  0.07667085,
       -0.17627513, -0.04133784,  0.25034377, -0.17164004,  0.16634598,
        0.18308365,  0.08592145,  0.08905195,  0.11517368,  0.04827499,
       -0.08297287,  0.03901137, -0.15337615, -0.08358597,  0.01340009,
       -0.05940268,  0.05974644,  0.03913205])

def encode(image, jit):
    #Declare you :)
    known_image = cv2.imread(image)
    reversed_img =  cv2.cvtColor(known_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    face_location = face_recognition.face_locations(reversed_img)
    your_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(reversed_img, face_location, num_jitters = jit)
    return your_face_encoding

# new = encode("Ani.png", 10)[0]
test = encode("Har.png", 10)[0]


print(np.allclose(face_encode, test))
```

You can test it with any image..
And u can print the `test` value (and compare with `person_encode` ) to make sure that the value (encode) is changed after computing the `new` encode.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are understanding right what is `num_jetters` is and what that "jittering" is doing (hint: jittering is changing your image slightly and RANDOMLY each cycle and makes face encoding for that changed image. And than returns some average value from all encodings). By default `num_jitters = 1` , so setting it in 0 is senseless.
Finally, when some A = B and after some manupalation  A <> B, it doesn't mean that both A and B are changed, it's enough the only one to be changed, right?

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Yes, It takes an input image and disturbs the colors as well as applied random translations, rotations, and scaling...
"RANDOMLY", but anyway you can run provided code (with the line "new = encode("Ani.png", 10)[0]" commented) a hundred times and you still get the same result ( face_encode == test ). But after trying encode another face (before "test"), the value (encode) for 'test' variable will be changed...